# Syntax error when making Redis call from Lua

Tags: redis

I get a syntax error ( `@user_script:15: ERR syntax error`) when trying to execute a `ZADD` with optional parameter `LT` from Lua in **Redis 5.0.12**:

```lua
redis.call('zadd', ASET, 'lt', 100, "A")
```

but the same exact code works fine on **Redis 6.2.1**

Is there some alternative way to pass optional parameters in older Redis versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work in Redis 5.0.12 because you're using a feature (the `LT` option) that wasn't added until Redis 6.2. From the [`ZADD`documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zadd#history):

> >= 6.2: Added the GT and LT options

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Was there a way in 5.x to add to ZSET only elements that are not already present regardless of the score?

Comment: @DavidSoroko: Sounds like you're talking about the `NX` option, which has existed for a while. But if you want to replicate `LT` you'd have to break it into different operations (first get the current score and then conditionally update it). That needs to be atomic, so the easiest way is to write a Lua script that comprises those operations.

Comment: Yes, I was misreading "Always add new elements" in `NX` description